# How do I change the background highlight color for a selection I marked with C-Spacebar?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlighting

I think that question explains it all. I tried changing highlight face but nothing happened.

Comment: Seems like this question is a duplicate, but I can't find its twin...

Comment: @Drew I found it on the normal SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684579/how-do-i-change-the-highlight-color-for-selected-text-with-emacs-deftheme

Comment: Then it's OK and need not be closed as a dup here. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That face you need to change is the `region` face.

The area you highlight with <kbd>C-space</kbd> is known as the region and is highlighted with a face of the name `region`.